# Error with .aux File when Compiling BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, auxiliary-files

When I try to compile my .bib file, I get the following error message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: DissertationProposal_07-02-17.aux
The style file: apacite.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 273 of file DissertationProposal_07-02-17.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {apacite}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibdata command---line 274 of file DissertationProposal_07-02-17.aux
 : \bibdata
 :         {Dissertation}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: Dissertation.bib
apacite.bst [2013/07/21 v6.03 APA bibliography style]
Warning--`others' not consistent with 6th ed. of the APA Manual
(There were 2 error messages)
```

What seems to be happening is that two \bibstyle commands are inserted into the .aux file. I looked at the .bib file, and I see no problems with it. What do I need to do to make BiBTeX compile properly?

Below is an example that outlines my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\geometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

I will use a simplification of the batch means stopping rule for MCMC suggested by \cite{JonesHCN06}. While Jones, et al. allow both the number of batches and the batch size to increase with each MCMC iteration, for computational simplicty, I will base the batch size on the square root of the maximum number of iterations, $s_\text{max}$:
$$ n_\text{batch}=\text{floor}\left(\sqrt{s_\text{max}}\right).$$
I will store the mean of every $n_\text{batch}$ iterations in a vector 
$$\textbf{b} = \left(\bar{Y}_1, \bar{Y}_2, \dots, \bar{Y}_{b_\text{max}}\right),$$
where $b_\text{max}$ is the maximum number of batches, and is given by
$$b_\text{max} = \text{floor}\left(\frac{s_\text{max}}{n_\text{batch}}\right) + 1.$$


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Dissertation}

\end{document}
```

Here is the `.bib` entry that is causing me trouble:

```
@article{JonesHCN06,
title={Fixed-width output analysis for {M}arkov chain {M}onte {C}arlo},
author={Jones, Galin L and Haran, Murali and Caffo, Brian S and Neath, Ronald},
journal={Journal of the American Statistical Association},
volume={101},
number={476},
pages={1537--1547},
year={2006},
publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This certainly doesn't come from the `.bib` file. What is your preamble and your document class?

Comment: What do you mean by compiling your bib file? You shouldn't compile your bib file at all!

Comment: Try removing all generated files (especially the `.aux`) and recompiling if you had an error you've fixed. Otherwise, can you give us a minimal example we can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @cfr, I have a reference that does not appear as cited. Instead of (Jones, Haran, Caffo, & Neath, 2006), which is what I should get, instead I get (!)JonesHCN06, which is the label I used to identify the citation in the `.bib` file. I thought that using `shift+ctrl+b` in WinEdt would compile the bibliography, and correct the citation error.

Comment: Then probably the error is there. But you've given no code, so impossible to say. When you run `bibtex`, do you get errors?

Comment: @cfr, When I run `BiBTeX`, the errors I get appear at the beginning of my post.

Comment: Do you get exactly those errors when you compile exactly the code you've posted in a clean directory?

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `$$` for display maths in LaTeX.

Comment: Obviously something is inserting a second `\bibliographystyle` command. So the solutions are: find the first occurence (probably loaded by some package in your preamble that you didn't show) and delete it or delete the second `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` before `\bibliography`.

Comment: @Bernard, I am using the `report` class. My preamble is stated above.

@cfr, I get the same error after I compiled the same code in a clean directory.

@Ulrike Fischer, All of the packages that I am loading appear in the preamble above.  I deleted the second `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` that appears before the `\bibliography, but I get the same error.

Is there a way to edit and save the `.aux` file without having LaTeX generate a new one each time I compile the `.tex` file?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to figure out how the second `\bibliography` statement ended up in the `.aux` file.

So, instead, I manually typed the citation, and followed it with `\nocite{JonesHCN06}` to make sure the citation appeared in the bibliography.